# How to auto-close another panel upon manually closing one panel

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms in a program in which i want to pass the input from form 1 to form 2. I want to close form 1 after form 2 is opened so that the program stops running when all forms stop showing up on the screen; However, i won't be able to close form 1 if i want to pass the value into form 2 (If i can in classes, please let me know) so i hide it after form 2 is open. This, consequently, results in the program running forever even after form 2 is closed, form 1 staying hidden. I want to close form 1 whenever the user closes form 2 using the Close (X) button. Any idea how to implement this? Also, i have already set the program to 'When the last form closes'.

Comment: Do you mean `Panels` or `Forms`? BTW, you can simply use `Panel1.Visible = False` to hide a panel.

Comment: Sounds Forms to me. If that so, then you could use **Application.Exit()** in the FormClosed event of any form except the MainForm you don't need to do that since the application exits when the MainForm is closed. Another option is to change the **Shutdown mode** in your project properties to _When last form closes_. Make sure in this case to dispose/close the forms not just hiding them.

Comment: i would need a condition in the main form using application.exit() when every form is hidden. Any idea how to set this up?

Comment: As already noted, this is a setting of your Project. See `Project -> Properties -> Application -> Shutdown Mode`. Choose `When last form closes` in the dropdown. To pass a value from Form1 to Form2, add a public property to Form2 and set it when Form1 opens Form2. Show Form2 and close Form1. When Form2 is closed, the Application shuts down.

Comment: _i would need a condition in the main form using application.exit() when every form is hidden._ I'm not sure about the **Hidden** thing. Anyways, If you are HIDING your forms using Form.Hide or Form.Visible = False, then to achieve that you could use: _If Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form).Where(Function(a) a.Visible).Count = 1 Then Application.Exit()_ . On the other hand, if you are CLOSING the forms using Form.Close or Form.Dispose, then you should use: _If Application.OpenForms.Count = 1 Then Application.Exit()_ instead.

Comment: In Form2 Loading or Shown event you can do all those things that you want. You can also close other forms in closing or closed events as well.

Comment: @JQSOFT where i do set up this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, i have already set the program to 'When the last form closes.

You almost there.

As I understand, you are keeping the Form1 opened but hidden to access it's members and/or objects from Form2 and that is the only reason why you are keeping Form1 opened.

You could solve this problem by creating a parameterized constructor in Form2 to pass whatever you need from Form1 before you close it.

```
Sub New(obj1FromForm1 As obj1Type, obj2FromForm1 As obj2Type, ....)
    Me.New 'Don't forget this!

    'Update Form2 accordingly...
End Sub
```

Where the *obj1Type, obj2Type* are the types of the passed objects. (Integer, String, ...etc.)

You could also declare class variables to refer to these objects if you need to access theme later somewhere in your Form2's code.

```
Private obj1 As obj1Type
Private obj2 As obj2Type

Sub New(obj1FromForm1 As obj1Type, obj2FromForm1 As obj2Type, ....)
    Me.New

    obj1 = obj1FromForm1
    obj2 = obj2FromForm1
End Sub
```

Now back to your Form1. Make sure that you **Close** it once you create Form2 using its new parameterized constructor and showing it.

```
Private Sub Form2Caller()
    Dim f As New Form2(obj1 As obj1Type, obj2 As obj2Type, ....)

    f.show

    Me.Close() 'and not Me.Hide nor Me.Visible = False.
End Sub
```

One last point. Don't pass disposable objects to Form2 that will be disposed by Form1 when you close it.

Good luck.